# Number of possibilities to draw from a card deck isn't an integer - where's my error?

Tags: probability

I have a deck of 40 cards containing A,K,Q,J,10 of the 4 suits, each twice. I want to calculate the number of possibilities to draw 4 cards *ignoring the suit*.

For the first card, I have 5 possibilities, for the second also, and so on. So I get 5^4 possibilities.

Ignoring the suit means dividing out the permutations of a given draw. For the first card, I have 4 possibilities, for the second 3, and so on. So I need to divide by 4!

But 5^4/4! = 625/24 = 26.04 isn't an integer! Where's my error?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean 20 cards?

Comment: Why do you want to dovide by $4!$? Why should the suit colour of the $K$ bre related to the cuit of the $A$? Your calculation is not founded

Comment: If order matters then there are $5^4$ possible patterns, though there are not of equal probability.  But you would not divide the $1$ pattern of four Aces by $4!$ to get the number of unordered paterns

Comment: Sorry, my problem statement was poor. First, I'm talking about 40 cards, I forgot to mention that each card is there *two times*. Second, I see now that dividing by 4! is wrong. I don't see yet how to get the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you’ve incorrectly identified the nature of the problem.

Let $n_A,n_K,n_Q,n_J$, and $n_{10}$ be the numbers of aces, kings, queens, jacks, and tens in your set of $4$ cards. In effect you’re asking for the number of solutions in non-negative integers to the equation

$$n_A+n_K+n_Q+n_J+n_{10}=4\;.$$

This is a standard [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem, and the solution is given by the binomial coefficient

$$\binom{4+5-1}{5-1}=\binom84=70\;.$$

A fairly clear explanation of the formula and its derivation is given in the linked article.

Comment: Thanks! Reading this will take me a bit of time. What seems a bit strange at first sight is that your answer doesn't seem to depend on the deck size.

Comment: @Marc: You’re welcome! No, it doesn’t depend on the size of the deck; all that matters is that the deck contains at least $4$ of every rank, and that there are $5$ ranks. If there were only $3$ aces, for instance, the calculation would have to be modified, since the solution $$4+0+0+0+0=4$$ would no longer be possible. (In this simple case it would be the only impossible solution, so we’d lose just one and have $69$.)

Comment: Ah, ok! I get back in case I have trouble with the article. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

first of all, 5 cards in 4 suits is 20, not 40. So either you have all cards double, or you have a typo.
Second, 5^4 is only if you put back the cards, otherwise you'd have 20*19*18*17, and you'd have to find a different way of ignoring suits.

Comment: I actually have all cards two times, see my comment above. Your criticism sounds valid. I don't see yet how to correctly ignore the suit or how to put what you say together with what Brian M. Scott says.

Answer (score 0):

- Four of the same rank: number of possible ranks so $5$
- Three of one rank, one of a different rank: so $5\times 4=20$
- Two of one rank, two of another: so ${5 \choose 2} = 10$
- Two of one rank, one of another, one of a third: so $5 \times {4 \choose 2} =30$
- All four different ranks: ${5\choose 4} = 5$

$5+20+10+30+5=70$ possible patterns but they are not equally probable

Comment: So the same answer as Brian M. Scott, but with a different approach

Comment: Thanks Henry, that helped another bit! What I don't get yet is the usage of the (x over y). I will read up on this.

Comment: [Combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) or [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)